# How convert a array object saved as string(base64?) to C# array or sql Table?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

I have a legacy code that was developed in Ruby, it saves an Array as a string in the database that I would like to decode in the migration to the new environment.

Legacy Ruby Code:

```
class CatalogoConjunto
  include DataMapper::Resource

  ...
  property :coordenadas, Object
  ...

  ...

  def save_depois
    if (coordenadas.length > 1 and coordenadas.include?([0, 0]) rescue false)
      self.coordenadas = coordenadas - [[0, 0]]
      save!
    end
  end

  def save
    save = super
    save_depois
    save
  end

  ...
end
```

Samples what saves in the column coordenadas:
"BAhbCFsHaQHYaQIDAVsHaQLZAWkCwwFbB2kB8WkCXQI= "

Other Samples:
"BAhbBlsHaQHRaQI6AQ== ", "BAhbBlsHaQLMAmkB3A== ", "BAhbB1sHaQKmAmkB81sHaQIkA2kBvQ== "

How do I find the encode method?

The new application uses C# and the data migration is being done in SQL ... but any light that shows me the way forward already helps me ...

Ruby makes me pretty lost.

**Edit**

The string "BAhbBlsHaQJ6A2kCIwI=" stand for this values (890, 547).

but using The following code i get the string "egMAACMCAAA="

Trying convert using C#

```
int[,] test = new int[,] { { 890, 547 } };

byte[] result = new byte[test.Length * sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(test, 0, result, 0, result.Length);

var anotherString =  Convert.ToBase64String(result);

Console.WriteLine(anotherString);



var stringFromDatabase = "BAhbBlsHaQJ6A2kCIwI= ";

byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(stringFromDatabase);

//Don't work
int[,] newArr = new int[byteArray.Length / sizeof(int)/2 + ((byteArray.Length / sizeof(int))%2), 2];
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < byteArray.Length / sizeof(int); ctr++)
{
    if (ctr % 2 != 0)
    {
        newArr[ctr/2, 0] = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray, ctr * sizeof(int));
    }
    else
    {
        newArr[ctr/2, 1] = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray, ctr * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

The string generated by Ruby looks like Base64 but the values don't match

Comment: If you aren't using the Ruby code, why do you even need to "convert" anything. Your questions seems to just be asking how to convert Base64 string to C# array.Your code doesn't appear (at least what you posted) to encode/decode anything, as we have no idea what `save` or `super` does.

Comment: I mention Ruby because seens like Base64, but i not sure, i only need know the way that (890, 547), ends as "BAhbBlsHaQJ6A2kCIwI=" in the database...

This is the only code that mentions "coordenadas" without being just to access

Comment: Base64 is not Ruby, it is its own thing, and most languages, including C# have functions for it. It is basic string encoding, used widely for XML, HTML, etc as a uniform way to ensure all characters are "legal" and offer some compression. C# has it easily accessible in [`Convert.FromBase64String`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiSpLCkvOPcAhVCU30KHby5BhUQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.convert.frombase64string(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AOvVaw14YjHGufgElJEe657XX-O5).

Comment: As I said, your Ruby code shows absolutely nothing about Base64 encoding. Best guess is that `super` in the `save` method might do something, but you don't show that. `Object` does not have a `save` function, so whatever code you are using must implement that somewhere else. To summarize, it is impossible to have your question answered on "how is it saved in Ruby" with what you have given.  It is quite possible it is not Base64 at all, or the string encoding is not being handled, though UTF-8 would be the norm.

Comment: On a second look, it is not Base64 at all. Your example strings are not properly formed Base64.

Comment: Your first sample decodes to `[[junk1[junk2[junk3]`'  If I had to guess, that's an array of binaries with open square brackets used as a separator, within a pair of square brackets.  But the others don't have a closing bracket at the end.  So my guess the way to do this is to walk the byte-array, ignore the initial open-bracket, and use any other '[' as a separator, and everything between them as binary data you need to convert to an integer somehow.

Comment: It looks like open-square-bracket is the separator, and there's binary data in between them.  I tried writing a little parser for the bytes between the separators (it just shifted each unsigned byte to the left by 8 and accumulated),  However, because all of your strings start with "BAhb", the data always starts the same 0x04, 0x08, 0x5b (that bracket).  There are patterns in there, but unless someone tells you how to decode them, you're going to pull all your hair out.

Comment: From the DataMapper (http://datamapper.org/docs/properties.html) site i discovered that Objects are stored marshalled by default...

And here (https://ilyabylich.svbtle.com/ruby-marshalling-from-a-to-z) how Marshal.dump work in Ruby...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataMapper has a default bahavior to marshall the data type Object:

https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/property/object.rb

After some research found a post of how Marshall in Ruby work here:

https://ilyabylich.svbtle.com/ruby-marshalling-from-a-to-z

I just need the numbers them i did a simple decode just looking for the Integers

```
public static List<int> Conversor(string stringFromDatabase)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(stringFromDatabase);

    List<int> retorno = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((char)byteArray[i] == (char)105)
        {
            int valInt = 0;
            int primeiroByte = Convert.ToInt32(byteArray[i + 1]);
            if (primeiroByte == 0)
                retorno.Add(0);
            else if (primeiroByte > 4)
                retorno.Add(primeiroByte - 5);
            else if (primeiroByte > 0 && primeiroByte < 5)
            {
                valInt = byteArray[i + 2];
                for (int y = 1; y < primeiroByte; y++)
                {
                    valInt = valInt | (byteArray[i + 2 + y] << 8 * y);
                }
                retorno.Add(valInt);
            }

        }
    }

    return retorno;
}
```